# Xamarin Forms Android Subscription purchase

Tags: xamarin.forms, in-app-billing

We have an XF Forms app that we are adding subscription support for. We implemented Plugin.InAppBilling. Works as expected on iOS. We followed JM's docs for configuring on Android - but getting "This app not configured for subscriptions" error.

This is the purchase method we are using:

```
public async Task<InAppBillingPurchase> MakePurchase()
    {
        if (!CrossInAppBilling.IsSupported)
            return null;


        var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();
        if(currentPage != null)
        {
            var confirm = await currentPage.DisplayAlert("Q5id subscription", "Become a subscriber to create an alert to find your loved one.","Confirm", "Cancel");
            if (!confirm) return null;
        }
        var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
        try
        {
            var connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();

            if (!connected)
            {
                //Couldn't connect to billing, could be offline, alert user
                return null;
            }
            //try to purchase item

            
            var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID, ItemType.Subscription);
            deviceService.DeviceLog("PurchaseAsync purchase: ", purchase);
            var isFinish = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.FinishTransaction(purchase);
            deviceService.DeviceLog("PurchaseAsync isFinish: ", isFinish);
            return purchase;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error MakePurchase: " + ex.Message);
            deviceService.DeviceLog("Error MakePurchase: ", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            await billing.DisconnectAsync();
        }
    }
```

We have verified bundleid, Play Console looks right. Any ideas?